# clang-format won't attach brace if there is a newline

Tags: c++, clang-format

I got a problem regarding clang-format:

What I want to enforce is that braces at the start of blocks are always attached to the function head / control sequence ...

This means that instead of

```
int f()
{
     return 1;
}
```

or

```
if(o < 1)

{
    return -1;
}
```

`clang-format` should *always* attach the opening brace like this:

```
int f() {
     return 1;
}
```

and

```
if(o < 1) {
    return -1;
}
```

While this works for the first case (no newline between function head and brace), it does not work if there is a newline between the function head / `if` etc.

I did not find any option for `clang-format` that enforces this.
The option closest to what I am looking for is `BreakBeforeBraces: Attach`, but this did not format the second case properly either. Playing around with this option as well as the options underneath `BraceWrapping` did not solve the issue as well.
Is there a way to configure `clang-format` to join lines such as the opening brackets always end up at the end of the last line of code before them?

I played around with online configurators like https://clangformat.com/ or http://cf.monofraps.net/ but could not find an option set that would serve my needs.

I am currently using clang-format version 3.8 .

Comment: Have you tried BreakBeforeBraces: Allman ?

Comment: @katrasnikj: Yes,  I did, but it did not solve the problem though. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: For small functions run clang-format with  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58802059/10063119 SFS_All & then remove it and add  correct braces setting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 0
```

This would cause the empty lines to be deleted, and then the braces would get formatted the way you request.

However, I expect this is not really a good solution for you, because it will delete *all* empty lines, not just the empty lines before a brace.

Other than this, I don't think this is possible with clang-format 6.0.0. I don't think it has been added in newer versions either - nothing in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) seems to relate to this.