# Why doesn't clang-format break before braces of getter?

Tags: c++, code-formatting, clang-format

The answer of the related post [how to make clang-format add new line before opening brace of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477654/how-to-make-clang-format-add-new-line-before-opening-brace-of-a-function/29504889#29504889) does not help.

I am using clang-format 9.0.0 with Cppstyle in Eclipse CDT on Windows. clang-format formats the following getter like this:

```
int returnNumber() { return 3; }
```

but I prefer the format

```
int returnNumber()
{
    return 3;
}
```

I have not been able to make clang-format do that, neither with breaking style `BS_Allman` nor with a custom style. Is there another solution than manual formatting?

My example source file looks like this:

Header.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Test
{

class MyClass
{
public:
    int returnNumber() { return 3; }
};

} /* namespace Test */
```

And my configuration file looks like this:

```
Language: Cpp

AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: 'true'

BreakBeforeBraces: Allman

ColumnLimit: '80'

IndentWidth: '2'

NamespaceIndentation: None

Standard: Cpp11

TabWidth: '2'

UseTab: Always

PointerAlignment: Left

AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign

BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon

MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
```

Comment: `clang-format` should be able to do that. can you run it manually on your sourcefile with the same config and see what happens?

Comment: When I run it from the console with `clang-format Header.h > Out.h` I get the same (bad) result: the getter is being contracted into one line.

Comment: Can you update the question with the `clang-format.config` file you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your config is that you missed this option that controls the behavior of `clang-format` with short function.

Add this to your config and eveything will be good:

```
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
```

---

Quoting from the [clang-format documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine (ShortFunctionStyle)
>
> Dependent on the value, `int f() { return 0; }` can be put on a single line.
>
> Possible values:
>
> - `SFS_None` (in configuration: None) Never merge functions into a single line.
> - `SFS_InlineOnly` (in configuration: InlineOnly) Only merge functions defined inside a class. Same as “inline”, except it does not
>     implies “empty”: i.e. top level empty functions are not merged either.
> - `SFS_Empty` (in configuration: Empty) Only merge empty functions.
> - `SFS_Inline` (in configuration: Inline) Only merge functions defined inside   a class. Implies “empty”.
> - `SFS_All` (in configuration: All) Merge all functions fitting on a single line.

Comment: For some reason `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None` doesn't do anything. I'm afraid it conflicts with maybe another option. But I'm really lost now.